# Find 2nd largest int in a ArrayList

Tags: java

I am creating a method that will take in the values of an ArrayList and return the 2nd largest int. I cannot use a sorting mechanism to change the ArrayList. Here is what I have so far:

```
public static int secondLargestInt(ArrayList<Integer> arr) {
    int max = arr.get(0);
    int max2 = arr.get(0);
    for(int i = 1; i < arr.size(); i++) {
        if(arr.get(i) > max) {
            max2 = max;
            max = arr.get(i);
        }
        if(arr.get(i) > max2 && arr.get(i) != max) {
            max2 = arr.get(i);
        }
    }
    return max2;
}
```

My method seems to work for most test cases except for the input of [100, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
Expected output: 5

My output: 100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to initialize `max2` to a lower value than any you could find, `MIN_VALUE` fits very well.

```
int max2 = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
```

---

To simplify a bit, you can initialize both to `MIN_VALUE` and use for-each loop do avoid indexing

```
public static int secondLargestInt(List<Integer> arr) {
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE, max2 = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (Integer value : arr) {
        if (value > max) {
            max2 = max;
            max = value;
        } else if (value > max2 && max > value) {
            max2 = value;
        }
    }
    return max2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your starting value for both `max` and `max2` is the value at index 0, which in your example is also the absolute maximum. Therefore no other element is ever bigger than any of them and they remain 100. You can assign the minimal integer value to both as suggested, but more effective would be to simply do

```
int max = Math.max(arr.get(0), arr.get(1));
int max2 = (max == arr.get(0)) ? arr.get(1) : arr.get(0);
```

That way you have the first two elements already checked and can start iteration from the third. More importantly - I believe the intent of the code is clearer that way.